# Определение разницы двух списков, состоящих из списков

Tags: python

имеется 2 списка, которые включают в себя списки из 3 элементов.
Как определить их разницу (какие отсутствуют и т.д)
До этого использовал конструкцию перевода в set и разности двух set

```
print(set(list_purchase_in_table_site) - set(add_new_purchase_site()))
```

Но как работать когда список, уже содержит другие списки.
Можно конечно перебором каждого элемента в внутреннем списке, но может есть более хороший способ?

Пример:
**Список 1**

```
[['Межгалактический щит', '1', '58'],
 ['Банка баранок', '100', '100'],
 ['Плащ черный', '1', '900'],
 ['Удленитель глаза', '3', '1234'],
 ['odwyz', '36', '05'],
 ['fxzqp', '04', '36'],
 ['jyvpo', '11', '47'],
 ['rfdhb', '31', '40']]
```

**Список 2**

```
[['odwyz', '05', '36'],
['fxzqp', '36', '04'],
['jyvpo', '47', '11'],
['rfdhb', '40', '31']]
```

**Разность**

```
[['Межгалактический щит', '1', '58'],
     ['Банка баранок', '100', '100'],
     ['Плащ черный', '1', '900'],
     ['Удленитель глаза', '3', '1234']]
```

Update:

```
def different_list(list1, list2):
    #list2 > list1
    # diff=[x for x in list1 if x not in [y for y in list2]]
    diff = [x for x in list1 if x[0] not in [y[0] for y in list2]]
    return diff

 list1 =    [['Межгалактический щит', '1', '58'], ['Банка баранок', '100', '100'], ['Плащ черный', '1', '900'], ['Удленитель глаза', '3', '1234'], ['htzwt', '02', '30'], ['hrhsy', '65', '37'], ['yzils', '90', '43'], ['cgzso', '48', '26']]
set2 = [('Межгалактический щит', 1, 58.0), ('Банка баранок', 100, 100.0), ('Плащ черный', 1, 900.0), ('Удленитель глаза', 3, 1234.0)]
```

Результат `[['htzwt', '30', '02'], ['hrhsy', '37', '65'], ['yzils', '43', '90'], ['cgzso', '26', '48']]`

```
different_list(list_add_in_table_site, list(set_in_database))
```

Почему порядок меняется? Или это из-за кортежа? (с базы данных возвращаю).

x

Comment: Странно. у меня ваш код не меняет порядок значений в списках. Да и разница списков не в кортежах задана, так что она здесь ни при чем должна быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst1=[['Межгалактический щит', '1', '58'],
['Банка баранок', '100', '100'],
['Плащ черный', '1', '900'],
['Удленитель глаза', '3', '1234'],
['odwyz', '36', '05'],
['fxzqp', '04', '36'],
['jyvpo', '11', '47'],
['rfdhb', '31', '40']]

lst2=[['odwyz', '05', '36'],
['fxzqp', '36', '04'],
['jyvpo', '47', '11'],
['rfdhb', '40', '31']]

diff=[x for x in lst1 if x[0] not in [y[0] for y in lst2]]
print(diff)
```

Результат:

```
[['Межгалактический щит', '1', '58'],
['Банка баранок', '100', '100'],
['Плащ черный', '1', '900'],
['Удленитель глаза', '3', '1234']]
```

Видимо, вопрос задан не вполне четко. Если нужно проверить полное совпадение списков, то генератор можно упростить, **принимая во внимание, что порядок значений в каждом списке важен** (пришлось поменять условие для наглядности):

```
lst1=[['Межгалактический щит', '1', '58'],
['Банка баранок', '100', '100'],
['Плащ черный', '1', '900'],
['Удленитель глаза', '3', '1234'],
['odwyz', '36', '05'],
['fxzqp', '04', '36'],
['jyvpo', '11', '47'],
['rfdhb', '31', '40']]

lst3 = [['odwyz', '36', '05'],
['fxzqp', '04', '36'],
['jyvpo', '11', '47'],
['rfdhb', '31', '40']]

diff=[x for x in lst1 if x not in [y for y in lst3]]
print(diff)
```

Результат:

```
 [['Межгалактический щит', '1', '58'],
 ['Банка баранок', '100', '100'],
 ['Плащ черный', '1', '900'],
 ['Удленитель глаза', '3', '1234']]
```

Comment: ваш скрипт проверяет только по первому элементу, что не совсем корректно

Comment: @danilshik мой скрипт проверяет по первому элементу, потому что так сказано в вашем вопросе (см. желаемый результат).

Comment: у меня порядок меняется во внутреннем списке

Comment: @danilshik то есть, второй мой скрипт тоже не решает проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить, что у вас опечатка, и список `lst3` должен выглядеть немного иначе

```
[['odwyz', '36', '05'],
['fxzqp', '04', '36'],
['jyvpo', '11', '47'],
['rfdhb', '31', '40']]
```

И если порядок элементов во вложенных списках фиксирован, то можно написать так:

```
set(map(tuple, lst2)) - set(map(tuple, lst3))

{('Банка баранок', '100', '100'),
('Межгалактический щит', '1', '58'),
('Плащ черный', '1', '900'),
('Удленитель глаза', '3', '1234')}
```

Comment: @gil9red потому-что элементы множества, как и ключи словаря, должны быть хешируемыми. Так-как списки это изменяемая структура данных -> не хешируемая -> не может быть элементом множества/ключом словаря, в отличии от кортежа.

Comment: да у меня опечатка, только сейчас заметил